# SQL command line showing empty set despite tables in database

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line-interface, mysql-workbench

My database has tables in it but when I am trying to see those in the command line, it is showing empty set. How to handle this?

Comment: you should put some image and codes, for example show that you have a table and the result after you execute your command line, and then also put  the command line text here so people seeing this question can have better understanding of your problem, and raises the possibility of your issue to be solved by someone.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe have

1. Your table is not correct.   You can see your MySQL error log
2. use: `show table;`  in your database, If you can see it, Please use select * from  table

Comment: I used show table and it is showing no error, only empty set.

Comment: How did you create the table? if you show table has empty , there maybe not have table.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Re-execute your database from MySQL Workbench and update schemas....